# Cannot find the element for a button

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a test that searches for restaurants, i choose one, and then add it to a map.  I can find the restaurant I want easily but cannot seem to get to the button I am trying to get at.

Here is the code I'm using to pick restaurant from list:

```js
this.selectsAttraction = function() {
  attraction = "El Jefe Burger Shack";
  var addedAttraction = element(by.cssContainingText('div.name', attraction));
  // get ancestor (that accepts mouseover to show icons)
  var parent = addedAttraction.element(by.xpath('../..'));
  if (parent) {
    // scroll into view
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', parent.getWebElement());
    // mouse over the target row (in order to click on gear icon, it must be visible)
    browser.actions().mouseMove(parent).perform();
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    // find edit icon - third child and then the first element under that
    var editIcon = element(by.cssContainingText('span.button', 'Add')).click();

    //also have tried:
    /*var editIcon = parent.element(By.css("div:nth-child(2)")).element(By.css("span:nth-child(1)")); */

    browser.driver.sleep(2000);

  }
  //The below works but only if I search the restaurant name which will only come back with one result, if I search restaurant there are multiple results to choose from
  //element(by.css(".button.button-add")).click();
};
```

Here is the .html:

```html
<div class="search-item">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="name" data-bind="text: name">El Jefe Burger Shack</div>
    <div class="address" data-bind="text: $data.vicinity || ''">Rout 3, KM 34.5, Cll 14 De Julio, Luquillo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <span class="button button-add" data-bind="click: $root.addAttraction">Add</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search-item">
```

Any help would be fantastic a bit lost here *this is a nonangular part of the site and Sync is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually get to the button directly from `addedAttraction`:

```
var addButton = addedAttraction.element(by.xpath("../following-sibling::div/span[. = 'Add']"));
```

We are going one level up, getting the following sibling containing `span` element with "Add" text.